# Elastic potential energy

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy, elasticity

The formula for elastic potential energy is $\rm (1/2)kx²$, all that I am asking is why is it not $\rm kx²$. Here is my logic. Let us say that $\rm k$ is $\rm 2\ N/m$ which means that for the spring to move $\rm 1 \ meter$ you have to apply $\rm 2 \ N$ of force, if you want to move the spring $\rm 2 \ meter$, then you have to apply $\rm 2N$ and then $\rm 2 N$ again, so the work should be $\rm 2N×4m=8J$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try a site search: there are answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507004/strange-factor-of-2-in-hookes-law), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104045/calculating-elastic-energy-constant), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422944/potential-gravitational-energy-versus-potential-spring-energy), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466111/spring-force-potential-energy-and-work-done)...

Comment: ...[here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470660/where-does-the-half-of-potential-energy-go), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579993/does-work-done-on-a-spring-elastic-potential-energy)...

Answer (score 2):

> $\rm k$ is $\rm 2\ N/m$ which means that for the spring to move $\rm \ 1 meter$ you have to apply $2 \ N$ of force.

That's a misleading version of what $\rm k$ means, because when you first start stretching the spring almost no force is needed. $\rm k= 2 \ N/m$ means that when the spring has an extension of $\rm 1\  m$ the tension in it is $\rm 2 \ N$, and when the extension is $\rm 2 \ m$ the tension is $\rm 4\  N$ and so on. The tension rises proportionally to the extension. As you stretch the spring the force you must apply rises *continuously*.

The work done stretching the spring (and therefore the elastic PE) is the area under the graph of force against extension. *Read all about it in a textbook*!

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is assume that the force is constant.

Imagine that you keep contracting the spring: at the beginning it is very easy but then it gets harder and harder. So the work you do depends on the position $x$ you are at, it is not always $2N$ of force that you applay: the $k$ in the spring force means "if I contract the spring by $x$ the force is $-kx$", it does not mean that for each extra meter you need to apply $2N$!

The force of a spring (that you need to balance) is $F=-kx$ so it varies with the distance. If you compress it by one meter with $k=2N/m$ then $F=-(2N/m)*1m=-2N$. If you compress it by another meter (ending up at $x=2 m$) the force of the spring is $F=-(2N/m)*2m=-4N$. Which means that for the first half you did a work smaller than in the second half as the force was smaller! And if you divide the first meter in 2 sectors of 0.5 m in the first sector you do an even smalller work. And if you keep dividing, you notice that in each sector you do a different (and increasing with $x$) amount of work. The total work is the sum of all these works!

A quick argument would be to use the *average* force that you apply to compress a spring by a quantity $\Delta x$. At the beginning ($x=0$) you need to apply $0$ force. At the end, you need to apply a force $k\Delta x$, then the mean force is $f_m=(k\Delta x+0)/2$ and the mean work is mean force time displacement i.e.
$$W_m=f_m\Delta x = {1\over 2}k\Delta x^2$$

A more general derivation is using integrals. The definition of work is, for a displacement $dx$ at a position $x$ the small work you need is
$$dW = F(x)dx = kx dx$$

which means that for the total work you need to integrate this

$$W=\int^x_0 dW =\int kx dx={1 \over 2} k x^2$$
which is the potential energy you seek.